# iterate over function arguments and retain sort order in python

Tags: python, function, arguments, locals, ordereddictionary

I need to call a Stored Procedure in python. 
The wrapper function accepts n number of parameters.
Based on the parameter list, I need to quote or unquote the arguments. I also need to send a null parameter.

How can I iterate through the function argument and build the SQL string?

for eg. the stored proc call looks like this - SP_TEST('chrA',intB,chrC)

```
def execSp(a,b,c,d):
    <iterate through params and build param list>
    #If the parameter c is null the SQL should be built as below
    SQL="exec SP_TEST('a',b,Null)";
```

I tried using locals() however it returns an unordered list

Am new to python so any leads will be of great help.

Comment: It is usually a good idea to make the "face of the function" - that is, the interface to the rest of your program, as "friendly" as possible. Why do you need to have some arguments quoted, and others not? Seems to be making life more difficult... can the function not handle this?

Comment: Thanks for responding. We can write it such that the function handles it. However, this is a re-write of an existing app. Trying to minimise the number of code changes in the existing apps. The current UI layer makes a call with a set number of parameters and the we now need a python wrapper to call the underlying stored proc. The quotes is to handle strings as opposed to integers. There is the additional complexity of being able to pass NULL as part of the stored procedure call.

Comment: I understand now. I have posted an answer that I believe does everything you ask for - and if it doesn't, you should be able to figure out the changes needed quite easily.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding. Figured out different ways to solve this one problem. I just can't vote up on the answers (not enough reputation apparently :))..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does exactly what you want. It starts by initializing the list AV to all NULL, then iterates of the number of arguments supplied, and replaces them appropriately to form the query string that you wanted. The `SQL =` string adds quotes to the first argument only. Did I understand correctly what you were trying to do?

```
def execSp(*args):
  AV = []
  SQL = "exec SP_TEST(";
  for ii in range(0,4) :
    AV.append("NULL");
  ii = 0;

  for a in args:
    AV[ii] = str(a);
    ii+=1;

  SQL = SQL + "\'" + AV[0] + "\'," + AV[1] + "," + AV[2] + "," + AV[3] + ")";
  print SQL

execSp("hello", 1, 2, 3);
execSp("hi", 2, 3);
```

When I run this, I get

```
exec SP_TEST('hello',1,2,3)
exec SP_TEST('hi',2,3,NULL)
```

Comment: execSp("'); drop table CUSTOMERS; --")

Comment: The SQL injection angle is important. However, am stuck with an python db interface which does not allow me to use the cursor.execute statement. Will definitely include this as part of enhancement requests to open the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `*args` construct:

```
In [1]: def execSp(*args): print args

In [2]: execSp('abc', 1, 'xyz')
('abc', 1, 'xyz')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def execSp(*args):
    if len(args) != 4:
        raise SomeException()
    a,b,c,d = args
    <you can now iterate over args and use a,b,c,d as required>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def f(*args):
...   for a in args:
...     print a
... 
>>> f(1, 2, 3, 4)
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to build your own query? Usually, you would rely on the DB api to quote your arguments for you. This will avoid you suffering from SQL injection.

```
cursor.execute('exec SP_TEST(?, ?, ?)', a, b, c)
```